# How to correctly load a PHP file in another PHP file?

Tags: php, url, curl, include, include-path

I have trouble to find a way to load a php file correctly in another php file when the php file is included in another php file with include () and required_once(). I found that if 
Afile.php uses url such as `../controller/mycontroller.php` to include another php file in it, when Afile.php in been included in Bfile.php which is located in a different dir, the `../` will lead the Afile.php's url to a different dir that is based on Bfile.php.

I tried to use these PHP string to specify a file's url with a static one, so that there is no misunderstanding when there is multiple include among many .php files. But it did not work!

Is there a better way to define a file location of a .php file so that when I want to include, call or load the .php file that is in a different dir while itself is also included in other php file in other dir?

If there is any confusion please let me know.

Thank You

**Update**

```
define('PUBLICPATH', __DIR__.'/');
// I prefer to have the "root dir" not accessible from public dir
define('ROOTROOT', realpath(PUBLICPATH.'..').'/');
$pathnow= define('APPPATH', realpath(PUBLICPATH.'../application').'/');
echo 'pathnow:'.APPPATH;
```

It returned `pathnow:/` as result page in chrome

Comment: Use absolute paths. That way you'll stop having any problems.

Comment: with your udpate, `$pathnow` returns the result of the function define(). Check how define works on http://php.net/define . Replace your code by `echo 'pathnow:'.APPPATH; `

Comment: because realpath() return a real path. If it not exists, this will return false. Maybe `__DIR__` is not available with your php version, so you need to replace it by `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @Asenar An interesting trouble, I found the path returned with PUBLICPATH will be all `\path\mypath` style while what your code try to append `/` after that... Is it a typo? or seomthing need to be adjust in the code?

Comment: Addendum: when you develop php code, you can add the following at the beginning of your main script : `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. This way, all problem will be displayed

Comment: ok, I suppose you're on a windows machine for having `\`, I will edit again my answer to make it more generic

Comment: @Asenar Yes, I am using WAMP at the moment in the windowXP environment. Do you think __DIR__ is still the best / only solution in this case?

Comment: yes, `__DIR__`, or `dirname(__FILE__)` as alternative. See my editions for a more complete answer about that + the `/` and `\ ` thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is to define one constant `ROOT_PATH` (or more) in the first called script, then to use it in every include/require instruction. For example let's say you have the following tree:

```
/var/www/example.com            - 
/var/www/example.com/www         - your public directory, accessible from www.example.com
/var/www/example.com/application -
```

index.php

```
<?php
// for recent php version, __DIR__ just do it
define('PUBLICPATH', __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
// in case __DIR__ is not available use the following:
//  define('PUBLICPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// I prefer to have the "root dir" not accessible from public dir
define('ROOTROOT', realpath(PUBLICPATH.'..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('APPPATH', realpath(PUBLICPATH.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'application').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require(APPPATH.'bootstrap.php');
```

For classes definitions, you can also use an autoloader (with __autoload or spl_autoload_register ) to load classes without having to include/require their file before.

**EDIT:** I replaced `'/'` by `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to make it work on both window and unix.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out and tell you what happens :)

Comment: I tried your methods, directly copy and past, but I found the result will not echo the path associate with the file, did I setup correctly? Plz see my update!

Comment: define('NAME', 'some value') create a constant `NAME` which fix its contents to `'some value'` (and this value cannot be changed further in the script).  Then you can do `echo NAME;` to display it, or use it with anyfunctions (do not add `$` or this won't work). by convention, everybody write constants in CAPITAL LETTER. see http://php.net/constants and http://php.net/define for better help :)