# how to include a php class file to another php file?

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP files, `cart.php` and `cart.class.php`

In `cart.php` file, I have a code of a shopping cart with a cart section and products section.

In the cart section, I want to display the products in the cart with a remove button.

In the product section, I have the list of products available with the add button.

All the `add` operation and `remove` operation want to be written as a class function in the `cart.class.php` file.

I want to include the `cart.class.php` file to the `cart.php` file when it executes.

Comment: [include](https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=011570197911755000456:fip9wopfz_u&q=https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjA_PTph5HmAhXczTgGHaYpB5UQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2AcRagnoqgP6XjSYL4pBLJ) or [require](https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=011570197911755000456:fip9wopfz_u&q=https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiq5Y37h5HmAhWQzTgGHZ-8AM8QFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3YpE84kCpvUPuiFFUG4fdI)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly load a PHP file in another PHP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194875/how-to-correctly-load-a-php-file-in-another-php-file)

Comment: Do you want to use your methods in `cert.php` ?